# Help adding Settings To Android Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, wallpaper

Hi I'm a bit of a novice developer looking for help from someone who has more of a clue then me lol. So I'm working on a project which you can download here, [Eclipse Project Link](http://droidspot.net/lwprojectnosettings.zip)

Sorry for the suspicious link but it's on my site and you can check it for viruses. Ok well I need help adding settings to choose which texture to show you should be able to tell what I mean because there are already two set up. i have the gui for the settings set up along with the activity I just can't figure out how to implement it. If you can help me I'll credit you in the app in the settings and the market post. Along with your name, website or, whatever on  my youtube channel in a video. Which can be found here, youtube.com/motodroidhelpandinfo. I have over 1,200 subscribers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is not for soliciting development.  You should phrase your question in terms of what exactly you are trying to accomplish, what you have currently, and what the problem with the current implementation is.

Comment: I already have all you ask in the original post. Also no where in the faqs or about did it say I couldn't solicit development, not that I think I am. I simply need help with a problem and am willing to credit the person who help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed an example or tutorial then your settings will be a preference activity that save to a shared preference, in order to use that in the program you use something like the following:

```
 SharedPreferences mPrefs = NexusRevampedWallpaper.this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);
 Boolean b = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Example Setting", true);
```

Where SHARED_PREFS_NAME which should match the name used in the preference activity. Hope I understood your question properly and that this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction. I'm not able to attempt it at this moment but I will try. If I can't figure it out I'll post the actual code instead of a link. Although I'm hoping I could get it myself.